# UITableView with CustomCell not show data Swift4 on Xcode9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, custom-cell

I read the other topics, but not solves my problem, I create a tableview and your cells with same value to make tests, but when I execute my project nothing data is showed. I put 5 size of rows to only to test. I don't know why my code not works.

My storyboard:
[image]

TableViewCellVenda.swift

```
class TableViewCellVenda: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageCloud: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelValorTotal: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelQtdItens: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelCliente: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelDataVenda: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

ViewControllerVendas.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // UI View
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewVendas: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var waitView: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    // DB
    var db: OpaquePointer?
    var count : Int = 0

    // Data
    var saleOrders : [SaleOrder] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.waitView.startAnimating()
        self.waitView.hidesWhenStopped = true

        tableViewVendas.delegate = self
        tableViewVendas.dataSource = self


    }

    // TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellVenda") as! TableViewCellVenda
        print("Cell for row")
        cell.labelCliente.text = "Nome do Cliente"
        cell.labelDataVenda.text = "14/02/1991"
        cell.labelQtdItens.text = "20"
        cell.labelValorTotal.text = "R$ 542,22"

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 75
    }


}
```

Emulator:
[image]

Comment: can you add a print statement inside cellForRow and tell if prints or not ?

Comment: Could you replace the screenshot with the one where contentView is opened. Select any control within it so that we can see the IBOutlet connections in the inspector.

Comment: @Sh_Khan yes, the print has been showed.

Comment: @Nitish I've edited with the new screenshot.

Comment: @Augusto Don't post the answer in your question. If you solved it yourself you can either post a full answer below if you think it will help future readers or you should delete the question.

Comment: @rmaddy, until in this case, that the solution is very simple, like change a option of constraints, serves as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a new swift UIKit file with a class of type UITableView and do all the tableview setup in there. And of coarse set the tables’s class as this UITableView class.